# ImageView dimensions update on orientation change

Tags: view, orientation

I have unexpected problem with obtaining view's dimensions on orientation change. 
I have my custom ImageView. In onDraw() method I get view's width and height via getWidth() and getHeight() and using these values I scale and move my image.

On activity's onConfigurationChange() I simply call setImageBitmap(bmp);

Everything is fine with that, but sometimes when orientation has changed, my ImageView in onDraw() still remember old values of it's width and height. 
How can I update it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to look at the life cycle of an activity... when the orientation change your application is entirely rebuild so you may save the current value in the onStop() and get this value back in the on Create, onStart() or onResume() methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

hope this help...

Comment: in OnCreate() I have a lot of different initializations (setiing many counters to 0), so I prefer to use onConfigurationChanged() to not re-create Activity.